# [ERROR] [1346057546.695789920]: Exception thrown when deserializing message of length [91] from [/nxt_lejos_proxy_mod]: Buffer Overrun

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[ERROR] [1346057546.695789920]: Exception thrown when deserializing message of length [91] from [/nxt_lejos_proxy_mod]: Buffer Overrun

in your opinion whic kind of error is this because it appears when I launch the nav stack but everything works fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42336/%5Berror%5D-%5B1346057546.695789920%5D:-exception-thrown-when-deserializing-message-of-length-%5B91%5D-from-%5B/nxt_lejos_proxy_mod%5D:-buffer-overrun/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-08-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error indicates that something went wrong when serializing the message or that the serialized message was corrupted during transmission. In your case, it looks like more bytes were received than required for representing some message sent by nxt_lejos_proxy_mod. Without knowing more about that node, it's hard to say what exactly went wrong.

It seems like connections stay valid if such an error happens. The subscriber that was throwing the error might work with corrupted data though.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2